# Displaying a Carbonate Ion with mhchem

Tags: mhchem, chemistry

I want to write out the formula for the aqueous carbonate ion using the mhchem package. If I write out CO3^{2-}, it looks the way it should be. (See image.)

[image: Ionic Equation - Normal]

However, I want to write out: CO3^{2-}_{(aq)}. The 2- charge gets shifted along to the right of the (aq) state symbol. (See image.)

[image: Ionic Equation - Incorrect]

Is there any means of fixing this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This is an interesting use case. 1. I'll try to find a solution for the next version of mhchem. 2. You could try the (still unofficial) option `superscriptstacked`. 3. As already pointed out, the IUPAC notation for that would be `CO3^{2-}(aq)`. (author of mhchem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
 \ce{CO3^{2-}_{\rlap{(aq)}}\; ->}
\end{document}
```

`\rlap` suppresses the width of the content, so you need a `\;` to get the correct spacing.

Comment: This does not quite sound as a consistent solution. How do you know that `\;` is the right amount of space? (Hint: you do not.)

Comment: @yo' Yes, I do not. It is the wrong one for sure. But it is reasonable. If you have a better answer, please post here ;-)

Answer (score 9):

You can use `{}_{(aq)}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
  \noindent IUPAC recommendation:\\
  \ce{2H+(aq) + CO3^{2-}(aq) -> CO2(g) + H2O(l)}

  \bigskip

  \noindent Subscript:\\
  \ce{2H+{}_{(aq)} + CO3^{2-}{}_{(aq)} -> CO2{}_{(g)} + H2O{}_{(l)}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind switching packages: the `chemformula` package in combination with the `chemmacros` package allows for a variety of different outputs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

IUPAC recommendation:\par
\ch{2 H+ \aq{} + CO3^2- \aq -> CO2 \gas{} + H2O \lqd}

\bigskip

\chemsetup{phases/pos=sub}
subscript phase descriptors after the compounds:\par
\ch{2 H+ \aq{} + CO3^2- \aq -> CO2 \gas{} + H2O \lqd}

\bigskip

phase descriptors as subscripts to the compounds directly:\par
\ch{2 H^+_{(aq)} + CO3^{2-}_{(aq)} -> CO2_{(g)} + H2O_{(l)}}

\bigskip

as before but disabled horizontal shift of the charge of \ch{H+}:\par
\ch{@{charge-hshift=0pt} 2 H^+_{(aq)} + CO3^{2-}_{(aq)} -> CO2_{(g)} + H2O_{(l)}}

\end{document}
```

[image]